# Perl: How can I capitalize a regex match?

Tags: regex, perl, capitalization

I am using this regular expression to find patterns in a genome.

```
$string =~ /(?i)a+t?|(?i)t+/g
```

To make the output easier to read I would like to modify it so it capitalizes anything it matches that is 4 to 7 characters long. Also it should not mess up the `$+[0]` or `$-[0]` variables.

the way i do the output is to get a sub-string from the larger string file based on the '$+[0]' and '$+[0]' i don't want to print out the regex matches i am printing out huge strings of correctors and i want the matches to stand out.

if you really need to see the code I'm working on you can get it [here](http://www.fiveeight.com/downl.html)

Comment: Why not just capitalize the output?

Comment: If you want to change the output, you'd better show the code that does the output.

Comment: @ysth & @Dimitar-Petrov get the code input and output [here](http://www.fiveeight.com/downl.html)

Answer (score 11):

With appropriate tests (for your match and for length (character groups with quantifiers like {4,7} are probably needed), without example content this is left to you) you could use an eval substituton `s/(match)/uc($1)/eg` which would take the matched string and make it uppercase then replace the match with the replacement.

As always read more at [`perldoc perlre`](http://p3rl.org/re) [`perldoc perlreref`](http://p3rl.org/reref) [`perldoc perlretut`](http://p3rl.org/retut)

As a sidenote, I have always wondered if Genomes are a good candidate for [`Regexp::Grammars`](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Grammars)?

Comment: No need for an "eval substitution". The replacement part of s/// is double-quotish so you can use a backslash escape without the need for s///e:   s/(match)/\U$1/g

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it's that easy.